# Spring: Unable to query repository with selected fields

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Before i explain my problem, i'd like to mention that none of the answers that are related to this issue worked for me. It might be either due to the actual question was never found on `stackoverflow` search or just the answers don't exactly apply to my issue.

So what i am looking for is to select an X amount of fields when i am doing a `findAll`, and i want to do this because the entity on which the repository is connected to has a join column and by default `JPA` queries the related data from another table, so i want the result of my query to be compact fast.

So i have `series` and `seasons` table, a `series` table has `One-To-Many` relation with `seasons`, meaning that one `series` record can relate to multiple `seasons` records. So when doing a `findAll` query for `seasons`, you can expect that `JPA` will also query `series` and insert its data as a sub-object inside `seasons` as the result.

The `seasons` entity looks like this:

```
package com.vod.cloudservice.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Date;

@Entity
@Table(name = "seasons")
public class Season {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "series_id")
    private Series series;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "create_time")
    private Date createTime;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "update_time")
    private Date updateTime;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "delete_time")
    private Date deleteTime;

    public Season() {
    }

    public Season(@NotNull String name, @NotNull Series series) {
        this.name = name;
        this.series = series;
    }

    /* Getters and Setters here */
}
```

And `seasons` repository looks like this:

```
package com.vod.cloudservice.repository;

import com.vod.cloudservice.entity.Season;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface SeasonRepository extends CrudRepository<Season, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT id, name FROM Season")
    List<Season> findAllSeasons();
}
```

As you can see, i want to select only `id` and `name` at least for the time being. And when i execute this method, `Spring` throws this error:

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.Long] to type [@org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query com.vod.cloudservice.entity.Season]
```

I've tried changing the query type to be native and adapt the actual query to be a `SQL` query, but it still throws the same error, so i don't know what to do this in case.

***Note***: I am still learning how `Spring` and `JPA` with `Hibernate` works, so i would really appreciate if the answer could give an explanation on why the suggested answer works that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections), you could create a projection:

```
public interface SeasonIdName {

    String getId();
    String getName();

}
```

and then use it the repository like this:

```
public interface SeasonRepository extends CrudRepository<Season, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT id, name FROM Season")
    List<SeasonIdName> findAllSeasons();

}
```

Comment: It feels like it would add more code than it's necessary, what if i want a another custom query?. does it mean i would have to create another interface just for that query?

Comment: If your custom query returns a different object, I would guess so.

Comment: @VinayHegde my goal is not to get multiple objects, i want ordinary values only. And as for this answer, i will upvote it for being a useful approach.

Comment: @VinayHegde I don't really understand how `JDBC Template` works, i will make a research of it and if it ends up being what i'm looking for, i'll create an answer explaining how i did it.

Comment: @VinayHegde 'its not a good idea to send interface to controller' - why do you think that, if you don't mind my asking? It will serialize just fine

Comment: I ended up using projection, since it seemed easier to customize responses with custom queries in a repository